# Redirect a port to url

Tags: apache, reactjs

I have build my application on node.js. It's running on port 8080, its accessible from domainname:8080. I want to access it directly (domainname), without using port number. Its on apache server

Comment: That's not generally possible, because all modern Web browsers default to port 80 for HTTP (or 443 for HTTPS.) So you'll need to make your webserver use port 80, or put a proxy HTTP server in front of it that does.

Comment: I want to access the url directly without using the port number

Comment: You can't, sorry, unless you either (a) change the port number used by Apache HTTPD to 80, or (b) put an HTTP proxy in front of Apache HTTPD that forwards requests from port 80 to port 8080. This isn't a development issue -- it's just the way web browsers are designed to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be done by reverse proxy.

Comment: If some one wants to hide this port, that means if someone wants to see all the contents in www.example.com rather than www.example.com:3000.

This can be done using reverse proxy. You need to add the below two lines in the virtual host entry of the domain in the apache configuration file.
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:3000/

Answer (score 0):

you can change the port number to default port 80 from apache configuration file httpd.conf for xampp 
and restart apache 
it will work if there is no another application use port 80 in your PC